# producing an array with the same number in

Tags: python, list

I want an array of size `80` and want to fill it with just one number. The number `1`, so `[1,1,1,1,1,80 times]` is there a quick method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since integers are immutable, you can safely do this:

```
[1] * 80
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
lst = [1] * 80
```

Note that with mutable objects (eg lists), doing this will create multiple references to the same list, so when you change one of the lists you change all the others. With immutable objects such as integers, strings, etc., this will work perfectly fine.

With mutable objects, you can do this:

```
lst = [[] for i in range(80)]  # or xrange in Python 2
```

This will create 80 separate lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
buildList = lambda val, size: [val for _ in xrange(size)]
buildList(1, 80)
```

Comment: Giving a name to a lambda function is an abomination